# Delaying promise requests when requesting information in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-play, request-promise

I am using the [gpapi](https://github.com/dweinstein/node-google-play) library in order to find the Play Store and store information about the apps found on the Play Store. I begin by finding the related apps of an app (about 20 apps), after which I request details about each one of them. This is done by the library as promise requests. I tried adding a delay between the requests, as in the current state, all the requests are executed simultaneously, thus I get a 429 error (too many requests), and after a while, I am temporarily completely banned from Google servers.

```
function getRelatedApps(pkg) {
    api.login()
        .then(function () {
            api.related(pkg).then(function (res) {
                for (let key in res['0'].child) {
                    let appId = res['0'].child[key].docid;
                    if (!storedApps.has(appId)) {
                        relatedArray.add(appId);
                    }
                }

                Promise.map(relatedArray, function (appId) {
                    getInfo(appId);
                }, {concurrency: 1});
            });
        });
}
```

I tried adding the `Promise.delay` between every request and using the `setTimeout` function without any effect, as the requests were still executed simultaneously.

When using a while loop with a `setTimeout` inside, no request was executed in general.

How could I make pauses between every call of the `getInfo` function?

Comment: Try something like -> `return Promise.delay(1000).then(() => getInfo(appId))`   ps. don't forget the return, or the map will instantly go to the next.

Comment: In fact remember to return all your promises.. eg.. `api.login()` -> `return api.login()`,    `api.related()` -> `return api.related()`   `Promise.map(` -> `return Promise.map(`  etc, otherwise your breaking your promise change, and errors promise completions are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bluebird, then you have `Promise.map()` and `Promise.delay()` available to you and you can do as follows:

```
function getRelatedApps(pkg) {
    return api.login()
    .then(() => api.related(pkg))
    .then(res => {
        let relatedArray = Object.values(res['0'].child)
            .map(value => value.docid)
            .filter(appId => !storedApps.has(appId));
        return Promise.map(relatedArray, appId => Promise.delay(1000, getInfo(appId)), {concurrency: 1});
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you can achieve the same effect with a home-grown `delay()` function and a [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) pattern, as follows:

```
function delay(ms, val) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve(val); }, ms);
    });
}
function getRelatedApps(pkg) {
    return api.login()
    .then(() => api.related(pkg))
    .then(res => {
        return Object.values(res['0'].child)
        .map(val => val.docid)
        .filter(appId => !storedApps.has(appId));
        .reduce((p, appId) => p.then(() => delay(1000, appId)).then(getInfo), Promise.resolve());
    });
}
```

Notes:

1. [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is available from Node.js 7.0.0 . For earlier versions of Node, revert to building `relatedArray` as in the question.
2. It is assumed that the question's `relatedArray` is initially empty.
3. Adjust the 1000 ms delay as required.

Comment: The first approach helped me achieved what I wanted. Initially, when I was using Promise.delay, I would use it as `Promise.delay(5000).then(() => doSmth());` instead of `Promise.delay(5000, doSmth())`.